# Only one whereHas is working in deep eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a deep eloquent relation.

What I’m trying to do is filter the `actions.treatmentActions.treatment.date` with `$date_range` and `actions.treatmentActions.paid` which equal `1`. The `date_range` filter is working fine, but the `paid` filter isn’t. The collection is still including the `actions.treatmentActions.paid` that equal to `0`

Any thought on this? am I missing something?

```
$polis = Poli::with('actions')
    ->whereHas('actions.treatmentActions.treatment', function ($treatment) use ($date_range){
         $treatment->whereBetween('date', $date_range);
    })
    ->whereHas('actions.treatmentActions', function ($treatmentActions){
        $treatmentActions->where('paid', 1);
    })
    ->where('id', '!=', 4)
    ->get();
```

I've tried different approach like this, but still not working:

```
$polis = Poli::with('actions')
    ->whereHas('actions', function ($actions) use ($date_range){
        $actions->whereHas('treatmentActions', function ($treatmentActions) use ($date_range){
            $treatmentActions->whereHas('treatment', function ($treatment) use ($date_range){
                $treatment->where('paid', 1)->whereBetween('date', $date_range);
            });
        });
    })
    ->where('id', '!=', 4)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with callback in `with`

```
$polis = Poli::with(['actions.treatmentActions' => function($query){
        $query->where('paid', 1);
    }])
        ->whereHas('actions.treatmentActions.treatment', function ($treatment) use ($date_range){
             $treatment->whereBetween('date', $date_range);
        })
        ->get();
```

Anyone can link me an article explaining this?